# "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes" with CLOB field

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have error when running a query, my error is related to CLOB. I didn't find solution to my problem.

I run this query:

```
  SELECT wm_concat( employee.id_employe )
    FROM decision decs 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN decision_to_employee dec_emp 
                         ON dec_emp.id_decision = decs.id_decision  
         LEFT OUTER JOIN employee employee 
                         ON dec_emp.id_employee = employee.id_employe 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_lang employee_lang  
                         ON employee.id_employe = employee_lang.id_employe 
                         AND employee_lang.lang_emp_lang = 'ar'  
   WHERE decs.id_decision = 'DEC-29' 
         AND dec_emp.type_to = 'to' 
         AND dec_emp.id_decision = decs.id_decision  
GROUP BY   decs.id_decision  

UNION  
  SELECT wm_concat( unit_lang.id_unit )
    FROM decision decs 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN decision_to_unit dec_unit
                         ON dec_unit.id_decision = decs.id_decision  
         LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_lang 
                         ON unit_lang.id_unit = dec_unit.id_unit 
                         AND unit_lang.lang_unit_lang = 'ar' 
   WHERE decs.id_decision = 'DEC-29'
         AND dec_unit.type_to = 'to' 
         AND dec_unit.id_decision = decs.id_decision 
GROUP BY decs.id_decision
```

but I have this error :

```
[APP] WARN [http-8080-1] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(100) | SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
[APP] ERROR [http-8080-1] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(101) | ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes ; expected: - ; got : CLOB
```

I think that this error appeared when I used `Union` in my query.

**Updated :**

```
decision : 

ID_DECISION : varchar2(15)
TEXT_DECISION : varchar2(4000)
NB_PAGE_DECISION : varchar2(15)
SUBJECT_DECISION : varchar2(15)
DATE_CREATE : date
USER_CREATE : varchar2(15)
NUM_ORDRE_DECISION : varchar2(20)
DATE_JC_DECISION : date
DATE_HJR_DECISION : varchar2(15)
TYPE_RECEIVE : varchar2(1)
DATE_RECEIVE : date
USER_RECEIVE : varchar2(15)
ID_TYP_CORRESP : varchar2(15)
ID_FOLDER : varchar2(15)
DOC_LINK_CORRESP : varchar2(15)

employee : 

ID_EMPLOYE : varchar2(15)
ID_JOB : varchar2(15)
ID_JOB : varchar2(15)
TEL_EMPLOYE : varchar2(15)
FAX_EMPLOYE : varchar2(15)
MAIL_EMPLOYE : varchar2(100)
STATUT : varchar2(1)
CONFIDENTIEL : varchar2(1)
NUM_IDENTITY : varchar2(15)
ID_PORTAL : varchar2(100)


employee_lang : 

ID_EMP_LANG : varchar2(15)
ID_EMPLOYE : varchar2(15)
FULLNAME_EMP_LANG : varchar2(500)
ADDRESS_EMP_LANG : varchar2(500)
LANG_EMP_LANG : varchar2(5)
MATRICULE_EMP : varchar2(10)

decision_to_employee

ID_DECISION : varchar2(15)
ID_EMPLOYEE : varchar2(15)
TYPE_TO : varchar2(5)



decision_to_unit : 

ID_DECISION : varchar2(15)
ID_UNIT : varchar2(15)
TYPE_TO : varchar2(5)


unit_lang : 

ID_UNIT_LANG : varchar2(15)
ID_UNIT : varchar2(15)
ADDRESS_UNIT_LANG : varchar2(500)
NBR_UNIT_LANG : varchar2(15)
NAME_UNIT_LANG : varchar2(500)
ABBREVIATED_NAME_UNIT : varchar2(15)
LANG_UNIT_LANG : varchar2(5)
```

Comment: Without knowing types of your fields we can't help you. Can you explain further?

Comment: Do parentheses to group subqueries help?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query has several issues:

1. You are comparing a `varchar` with a `numeric`, which is wrong: `decs.id_decision = 'DEC-29'`.
2. You are using `wm_concat`, which is undocumented. Use `listagg` instead.
3. You are grouping on `decs.id_decision` without using it in your result, which makes no sense to me.
4. You have a line feed between the first and second part. That can cause problems in some environments. Put it together.

Comment: LISTAGG was only introduced in Oracle 11g Release 2

Answer (score 0):

You should use UNION ALL instead of UNION
Refer [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:498299691850) reply for this error